# How does The Mimeoplasm and Reflections of Littjara interact

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I have [The Mimeoplasm](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=The%20Mimeoplasm) exile a horror for the copy ability and [Reflections of Littjara](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Reflections%20of%20Littjara) has chosen horrors, do I get a copy of Mimeoplasm (choosing 2 new creatures), the copied creature (without the counters), or does it not trigger at all?

Also if I choose ooze for Reflections of Littjara then do I get a copy of Mimeoplasm?

Comment: Hi Businessgoose, you may want to take the [tour].

Answer (score 6):

Since [Reflections of Littjara](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Reflections%20of%20Littjara) has a cast trigger, it will look at the Ooze type on The Mimeoplasm for determining a copy.

If you had chosen Ooze, you will then have two instances of The Mimeoplasm on the stack, and as each resolves separately and enters the battlefield, you would then exile 2 creatures and do the copying and adding counters for each instance.

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that in the "ooze" case, as Mimeoplasm is legendary you have to choose one of the copies to stay on the battlefield as a state based action.

Comment: @John Since it enters as a copy of the exiled creatures, unless you pick the same legendary creature from graveyards, it won't matter.

Comment: *grumble* dang it.  So many layers of complexity.  Thanks.  Wonder why Mimeoplasm is legendary then?  Seems like the legendary aspect of it would never matter except for Commander....  Ah, he came out in a commander set.  All is explained...

Comment: @JonTheMon you would need multiple copies of the same legendary creature in graveyards, since the token copy of the spell would resolve first, exile the ones chosen by it, then the creature wouldn't be in grave to be chosen by the second spell (they aren't targets and aren't chosen on cast)

Comment: @Andrew Correct, i should have probably said "creatures", but in the context of commander you'd have to pick from multiple graveyards as well.

Comment: @John not just in a commander set, he came out as the commander of the Devour for Power commander preconstructed deck.

Answer (score 2):

In "As The Mimeoplasm enters the battlefield", "The Mimeoplasm" refers to the permanent created by the spell. A spell is an object on the stack. If something "enters the battlefield", it's not on the stack, it's on the battlefield. So the permanent enters the battlefield as a Horror, but the spell was never a Horror.

If you had chosen "Ooze", then when you cast The Mimeoplasm, you would be casting a spell of the type Ooze, so you would get a copy of that spell.

Answer (score -1):

[Reflections of Littjara](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Reflections%20of%20Littjara)'s ability is

> Whenever you cast a spell of the chosen type, copy that spell.

Activating The Mimeoplasm's ability is not casting a spell, so nothing happens.

Comment: The Mimeoplasm's ability is not an activated ability, it is a replacement effect. And you don't address the last part of the question.

Comment: This is incorrect. First, the mimeoplasm has no activated abilities, second the ability it has is a replacement effect on ETB (614, 616.1c), which would be part of the spell resolving,. This question is about how that ETB replacement effect (which changes the creature's type) interacts with Reflections.